# Where I can find the documentation for Ubuntu Touch libraries?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, documentation

As far as I know Ubuntu Touch has some libraries like Hybris, platform-api and qtubuntu.

Where I can find clear documentation for those?

For example, I am interested in finding out what functions or classes they have, and what the meaning of "plugin" is in Ubuntu Touch architecture (what plugs in(to) what?), and whether platform-api functions can be used by applications directly or are plugged into some other interface like Mir...